# How to order the ties in data so that the previously observed value appears first

Tags: r, dplyr

```
ex <- structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), timestamp = structure(c(1504975114, 1504975115, 
1504975116, 1504975116, 1504975121, 1504975121, 1504975121, 1504975121, 
1504963482, 1504963486, 1504963486, 1504964343, 1504964343, 1504964394, 
1504964394, 1504964394, 1504964394), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), subgroup = c(36L, 36L, 36L, 35L, 36L, 35L, 
35L, 36L, 43L, 43L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 43L, 43L), A = c(1L, 
49L, 1L, 74L, 12L, 61L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 30L, 30L, 18L, 19L, 32L, 
40L, 32L, 40L), B = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("group", "timestamp", 
"subgroup", "A", "B"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

I've got a data like above. I want to sort the data within `group` by timestamp, but also pay attention how the ties in timestamp are handle. Precisely speaking, if two observations havae the same timestamp, I would like to have as first this observation, that has the same `subgroup` id as the value from previous timestamp. So the desired output would look like below:

```
    # A tibble: 17 x 5
    group timestamp           subgroup     A     B
    <dbl> <dttm>                 <int> <int> <int>
 1  1.00 2017-09-09 16:38:34       36     1     1
 2  1.00 2017-09-09 16:38:35       36    49     1
 3  1.00 2017-09-09 16:38:36       36     1     0
 4  1.00 2017-09-09 16:38:36       35    74     1
 5  1.00 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35    61     1
 6  1.00 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35     5     0
 7  1.00 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36    12     1
 8  1.00 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36     5     1
 9  2.00 2017-09-09 13:24:42       43     1     1
10  2.00 2017-09-09 13:24:46       43    30     1
11  2.00 2017-09-09 13:24:46       14    30     1
12  2.00 2017-09-09 13:39:03       14    18     1
13  2.00 2017-09-09 13:39:03       14    19     1
14  2.00 2017-09-09 13:39:54       14    32     1
15  2.00 2017-09-09 13:39:54       14    40     1
16  2.00 2017-09-09 13:39:54       43    32     1
17  2.00 2017-09-09 13:39:54       43    40     1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What if the ties are in the first rows? How can you use the previous subgroup ?

Comment: Then it would be great to check what's in the row after those ties and sort them to have the same subgroups adjacent to each other. So if the first two rows are ties with regards to timestamp and subgroups are `36, 35` we look at 3rd row and if there's `36` the order would be `35, 36, 36`.

Comment: Desired output is unclear.

Comment: @ashleych, the rows that had changed are `5:8` - as all of them have the same `timestamp` value and the value of subgroup from row `4` is `35` we place the `35` first in rows `5:6` and `36` later in rows `7:8`. Does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea using `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)
ex %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(order = map2(
    split_ <- split(subgroup,timestamp),
    accumulate(split_, ~intersect(c(rev(.x),.y),.y)),
    match) %>% unlist) %>%
  arrange(group,timestamp,order) 

# # A tibble: 17 x 6
# # Groups:   group [2]
#    group           timestamp subgroup     A     B order
#    <dbl>              <dttm>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1     1 2017-09-09 16:38:34       36     1     1     1
#  2     1 2017-09-09 16:38:35       36    49     1     1
#  3     1 2017-09-09 16:38:36       36     1     0     1
#  4     1 2017-09-09 16:38:36       35    74     1     2
#  5     1 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35    61     1     1
#  6     1 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35     5     0     1
#  7     1 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36    12     1     2
#  8     1 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36     5     1     2
#  9     2 2017-09-09 13:24:42       43     1     1     1
# 10     2 2017-09-09 13:24:46       43    30     1     1
# 11     2 2017-09-09 13:24:46       14    30     1     2
# 12     2 2017-09-09 13:39:03       14    18     1     1
# 13     2 2017-09-09 13:39:03       14    19     1     1
# 14     2 2017-09-09 13:39:54       14    32     1     1
# 15     2 2017-09-09 13:39:54       14    40     1     1
# 16     2 2017-09-09 13:39:54       43    32     1     2
# 17     2 2017-09-09 13:39:54       43    40     1     2
```

I made the assumption that timestamp are sorted before hand, if not, sort as a first step with `ex %>% arrange(group, timestamp) %>% ...`.

You can add `%>% select(-order) %>% ungroup` to get precisely your desired output (I left it this way to make it easier to understand).

---

## explanations

Let's keep only group 1 to illustrate what happens inside the mutate call:

```
ex1 <- filter(ex, group==1)
```

For each timestamp we make a list of subgroups:

```
split_ <- split(ex1$subgroup,ex1$timestamp)
# $`2017-09-09 16:38:34`
# [1] 36
# 
# $`2017-09-09 16:38:35`
# [1] 36
# 
# $`2017-09-09 16:38:36`
# [1] 36 35
# 
# $`2017-09-09 16:38:41`
# [1] 36 35 35 36
```

The order of the last item should be changed, `35` should come before `36`, because it's used last in the 3rd element. As `intersect` keeps the order of items in 1st argument, I can get the right order for the last item like this :

```
intersect(c(rev(split_[[3]]), split_[[4]]),
          split_[[4]])
# [1] 35 36
```

To apply this transformation to all elements I use `purrr::accumulate`, as I always need the last computed order to compute the next one :

```
acc_ <- accumulate(split_, ~intersect(c(rev(.x),.y),.y))
# [[1]]
# [1] 36
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 36
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 36 35
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 35 36
```

If I use `split_` and `acc_` with `match` I can get the order than these elements should have in our output

```
map2(split_ , acc_, match)
# $`2017-09-09 16:38:34`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`2017-09-09 16:38:35`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`2017-09-09 16:38:36`
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $`2017-09-09 16:38:41`
# [1] 2 1 1 2
```

Then I can `unlist` it get my `order_` column, and sort by `order_` to get the desired output.

Comment: This works really well! However, I have some troubles with understanding what happens inside mutate - could you please elaborate on the idea a little?

Comment: Hi @Moody_Mudskipper, would you have a look?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022075/how-to-order-the-ties-in-data-with-previously-observed-value-appearing-first-wit

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that would have usually worked.

```
library(dplyr)        
ex %>% 
arrange(group,timestamp,subgroup)
```

But this produces this output

```
 group timestamp           subgroup     A     B
   <dbl> <dttm>                 <int> <int> <int>
 1    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:34       36     1     1
 2    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:35       36    49     1
 3    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:36       36     1     0
 4    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:36       35    74     1
 5    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36    12     1
 6    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35    61     1
 7    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35     5     0
 8    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36     5     1
 9    2. 2017-09-09 13:24:42       43     1     1
10    2. 2017-09-09 13:24:46       43    30     1
```

the reason is the date time object also stores fractions of seconds, so while it appears that the timestamp of row 5 and 6 are the same, they are not. You can do a quick `as.numeric(ex$timestamp)` to check this out.

For now, I have rounded off the microseconds in the code below to produce the output that you seem to desire.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(lubridate) # to use round_date
ex %>% 
   arrange(group,round_date(timestamp, ".5s"),subgroup)

 group timestamp           subgroup     A     B
   <dbl> <dttm>                 <int> <int> <int>
 1    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:34       36     1     1
 2    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:35       36    49     1
 3    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:36       35    74     1
 4    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:36       36     1     0
 5    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35    61     1
 6    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35     5     0
 7    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36    12     1
 8    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36     5     1
 9    2. 2017-09-09 13:24:42       43     1     1
10    2. 2017-09-09 13:24:46       14    30     1
11    2. 2017-09-09 13:24:46       43    30     1
12    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:03       14    18     1
13    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:03       14    19     1
14    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:54       14    32     1
15    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:54       14    40     1
16    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:54       43    32     1
17    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:54       43    40     1
```

Comment: That is not correct, rows 3 and 4 as well as 10 and 11 should be swapped places as in previous rows (2 and 9 respectively) we've got `36` and `43` respectively. And yeah, I missed the fractions of seconds thing, but rounding to whole seconds as you did makes the example right.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the result that you want. I wonder if there is a more straightforward way to do this

```
library(dplyr) 

ex1<-ex %>% 
  mutate(timestamp=as.POSIXct(as.character(timestamp))) %>% 
  arrange(group,timestamp) %>% 
  group_by(group,timestamp) %>% 
  mutate(order=0,subgroup_lag=0)  # initialising variable to use in the for loop

ex1$group_id<-  group_indices(ex,group,timestamp) # creating a group_index, this will be used for splitting the dataset into multiple datasets 

ex_list<-split(ex1,ex1$group_id) # split by group_index
# this will create a list with datasets that have the same Group, and timestamp

for (i in 2: length(ex_list)){ # for each dataframe in the list ex_list
  if (nrow(as.data.frame(ex_list[[i]]))>1){ 

     ex_list[[i]]$subgroup_lag<-ex_list[[i-1]][nrow(ex_list[[i-1]]),]$subgroup #if there are multiple rows in a dataframe, obtain the subgroup value from the previous row
     #calling that value to be compared subgroup_lag 
     if(ex_list[[i]]$subgroup_lag>0){

       ex_list[[i]]$order <- ifelse(ex_list[[i]]$subgroup_lag == ex_list[[i]]$subgroup,1,0 ) #identify rows that have the same subgroup id as the subgroup_lag value, then mark order as 1
       # this is to sort easily in the next step
     }

  }
  ex_list[[i]] <-  ex_list[[i]] %>%
    arrange(desc(order)) # sort by order
}

df<-do.call(rbind,ex_list) # bind rows into a dataframe
df
```

the output is as below

```
group timestamp           subgroup     A     B
   <dbl> <dttm>                 <int> <int> <int>
 1    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:34       36     1     1
 2    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:35       36    49     1
 3    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:36       36     1     0
 4    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:36       35    74     1
 5    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35    61     1
 6    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       35     5     0
 7    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36    12     1
 8    1. 2017-09-09 16:38:41       36     5     1
 9    2. 2017-09-09 13:24:42       43     1     1
10    2. 2017-09-09 13:24:46       43    30     1
11    2. 2017-09-09 13:24:46       14    30     1
12    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:03       14    18     1
13    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:03       14    19     1
14    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:54       14    32     1
15    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:54       14    40     1
16    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:54       43    32     1
17    2. 2017-09-09 13:39:54       43    40     1
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I need something more efficient though, as my dataset is pretty large (1kk rows, 400 cols) and I'm waiting already for a half of hour for the result.

Comment: Try to identify which part of the code is slowing things down. You can comment out certain portions to check. My guess is  split is probably what is slowing it down. If so, try using Split via data.table package.

Comment: `Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)`

Comment: Il try sending you a vectorised version (instead of the for loop going through each row). Lets see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A vectorised solution. But I am afraid, it is not more effective than the for loop

```
vector_f<- function() { 
  ex$id<-seq_along(ex$group)

  ex1<-ex %>% 
    mutate(timestamp=as.POSIXct(as.character(timestamp))) 
  ex1$group_id<-  as.numeric(group_indices(ex1,group,timestamp))

  df_list<- list()
  for (i in 2:max(ex1$group_id)){ 
    df_list[[i]]<- ex1 %>%
      filter(group_id %in% c(i-1,i,i+1)) %>% 
      arrange(group,timestamp) %>% 
      group_by(group,timestamp) %>% 
      mutate(subgroup_1=last(subgroup)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      mutate(temp= lag(subgroup_1,n=1)) %>% 
      group_by(group,timestamp) %>% 
      mutate(subgroup_lag= first(temp,n=1)) %>% 
      mutate(order =ifelse(subgroup_lag == subgroup,1,0 ) ) %>% 
      arrange(group,timestamp,desc(order)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      filter(group_id %in% c(i))
   }
  df_list[[1]]<- ex1 %>%
    filter(group_id ==1 ) %>%
    mutate(subgroup_1=0,order=0,temp=0,subgroup_lag=0) %>% 
  ungroup()

df<-do.call(rbind,df_list)
  print(df)
}
```

When I do a comparison using the dataset that you provided, for loop shows much better results> its because, even when we are vectorising, we are forced to split the dataset into groups for comparison. So honestly, this is more a dplyr solution, with all benefits of vectorisation lost

```
> microbenchmark(vector_f(), for_f(), times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 vector_f() 58.03299 66.40527 73.79760 70.92226 78.58620 115.33876   100
    for_f() 12.64291 13.80850 16.32043 16.10607 17.63527  27.66872   100
```

I also ran the codes creating a dummy dataset of 8.5 Million rows, and here are the system times. I suggest removing the columns you dont need, and then add them back once this processing is done

```
system.time(vector_f())
   user  system elapsed 
 244.47    3.40  248.12 

system.time(for_f())
   user  system elapsed 
 218.61    0.71  219.50
```

Using a data.table based solution is likely to be faster