# How to order the ties in data with previously observed value appearing first with multiple sorting column

Tags: r, sorting, tidyverse

**Disclaimer:** Please note that this is extension, not a duplicate, to this topic: [How to order the ties in data so that the previously observed value appears first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014985/how-to-order-the-ties-in-data-so-that-the-previously-observed-value-appears-first). The difference is that now I don't have one, but many sorting column.

I need to sort attached data by min, then by sec, then by timestamp. Additionally, if there are any ties in order I would like to order those ties so that the same values of `subgroup` would be adjacent, i.e if two observations hava the same `min`, `sec` and `timestamp`, I would like to have as first this observation, that has the same `subgroup` as the value from previous `min`, `sec`,`timestamp` combination.

@Moody_Mudskipper provided excellent idea in the linked topic, however I don't know if it is applicable to my extended case. I tried to split based on all sorting variables, i.e. `split(subgroup, list(min, sec, timestamp)` but as my data is pretty large and I create all combinations of `min`, `sec`, `timestamp` it makes impossible to process that by my computer. So my question is - how can I tweak that solution? Is there any alternative?

```
structure(list(group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), subgroup = c("C", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"C", "L", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "L", "C", "C", "L", 
"L", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", 
"B", "U", "B", "B", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", 
"U", "B", "U", "U", "B", "U", "U", "B", "B", "U", "U", "U", "B", 
"B", "B"), A = c(32, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 61, 0, 50, 7, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 
61, 49, 0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 3, 0, 12, 0, 0, 
49, 0, 49, 0, 0, 49, 0, 0), B = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), sec = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 33L, 36L, 39L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 13L, 18L, 22L, 27L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 
33L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 43L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 
49L, 52L, 57L, 58L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
17L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 43L, 52L), timestamp = structure(c(1515945641.69, 
1515945641.69, 1515945642.273, 1515945643.69, 1515945647.69, 
1515945652.202, 1515945654.354, 1515945654.354, 1515945674.224, 
1515945677.592, 1515945680.129, 1515945683.176, 1515945684.514, 
1515945685.921, 1515945687.289, 1515945689.66, 1515945689.553, 
1515945692.633, 1515945692.643, 1515945694.34, 1525465421.403, 
1525465426.1, 1525465429.586, 1525465435.347, 1525465438.739, 
1525465439.499, 1525465440.315, 1525465441.211, 1525465443.314, 
1525465444.754, 1525465385.252, 1525465386.252, 1525465387.252, 
1525465388.252, 1525465451.143, 1525465451.342, 1525465453.603, 
1525465453.763, 1525465454.865, 1525465457.363, 1525465936.564, 
1525465940.29, 1525465944.562, 1525465946.26, 1525465947.762, 
1525465952.283, 1525465954.87, 1525465954.97, 1525465954.939, 
1525465956.282, 1525465958.77, 1525465959.506, 1525465960.404, 
1525465962.74, 1525465964.699, 1525465968.194, 1525465971.1, 
1525465975.106, 1525465991.138, 1525466000.25), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("group", "subgroup", "A", 
"B", "min", "sec", "timestamp"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -60L))
```

Desired order should be:

```
c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand yet from your question how you want to resolve ties based on prior subgroup. For instance I see two lines with min = 0, sec = 13, timestamp = 2018-01-14 16:00:54. One is subgroup C and one is subgroup L. The prior row above them had subgroup L. So in that case you wand L first? But what if there were multiple subgroups in the prior set of tied rows? How are those to be sorted?  It would help if you could show an example of what the output should look like for an edge case like that.

Comment: @JonSpring yeah, this lines illustrate the case. Previous row of `subgroup` is `L`, so the order of two lines should be switched. I want to check only direct previous value.

Comment: @Henrik, I have added the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same solution, but first define a columns to identify your groups identified by all grouping variables. I used `dplyr::group_indices` for that.

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(group_ind = group_indices(.,group,min, sec, timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    order = map2(
    split_ <- split(subgroup,group_ind),
    accumulate(split_, ~intersect(c(rev(.x),.y),.y)),
    match) %>% unlist) %>%
  arrange(group,group_ind,order) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-order, - group_ind)


df3 <-df[c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
     18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
     34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
     50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60),]


identical(df2,df3)
# TRUE
```